# iOS thread problem

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, spinlock

I load image by NSOparationInvokation and call out method in the main thread, which adds this image to scroll view, but app hardly lags. If I load image but not add it view, app works normally, if I add test button on view app also work normally and if I load image and add test button to view app don't lag. By profiler problem in __spin_lock. Someone knows what's wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When using threads on iOS, you should **never ever ever** make calls to `UIKit`. That's why it won't load. Put it on the main thread and it'll work.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/AboutThreads/AboutThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH6-SW2    "If your application has a graphical user interface, it is recommended that you receive user-related events and initiate interface updates from your application’s main thread. [...] Some frameworks, such as Cocoa, generally require this behavior, but even for those that do not, keeping this behavior on the main thread has the advantage of simplifying the logic for managing your user interface."

Comment: Yes, that's the long answer. +1 for the research effort.